# How can I model a relation with user and entity?

Tags: java, servlets, model

I am trying to add a feature on the "Bookshelf App for Java on App Engine Standard Environment" that lists books based on read or not read. The codes are available here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java
There is a Book.java file that defines the model a book. If I want to add the feature of read or not read do I add a boolean variable in Book.java? Is this a right approach? Or just keep a database table of bookID, user, readOrNot? Or the are some other smart approaches?

Comment: "*There is a Book.java*" - Which? There are multiple `Book.java` files.

Comment: There are four different version of the app. I was working with the 4-auth version.

Comment: Post your code here, do not refer it from external resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a class like Book.java should only contains properties specific to a book like title, author, published date. If you want to add information like number of pages, you would add it to the book class. In the case of the read or not read feature, it is better to keep this information in a database where book IDs would be attached to a specific user. The user class could keep a book read list but I would recommend a database class that exposes an API to get a list of books for a user. The code would be more reusable.
I hope this help you a bit.